# How can I download R to windows 7

Tags: r, installation

How can I download R to a Win7 computer?

I have been sent on a wild goose chase starting at tutorialspoint.com/r/r_environment_setup.htm.

I clicked on R-3.2.2 for windows (32/64 bit)

I got to a link that said Download R-4.3.0 for windows.
That page said I first had to download UCRT, I clicked on the x86 link.

That took me to microsoft.com/download/details.aspx:id=49071'

That page said that Internet Explorer was no longer available, and I got sent to a page to download Microsoft Edge, which I already have installed.

By this time there was no mention of UCRT, much less R.

Is there a simple way to download the R program?

Comment: These are to separate issues. You download R here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/. But it requires UCRT to run. So that you have to get from microsoft either by directly downloading it or through windows update.

Comment: Microsoft won't download it to Win 7, and I refuse to go to newer versions. I found an old version (I think 3.2) of R on a disc from an old computer. It runs fine on Win 7 without UCRT. What am I missing by not getting the newer version of R?

Comment: R 4.1 introduced a bunch of new functions (reviewed [here](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/new-features-r410-pipe-anonymous-functions/)). Even if you don't care about those features, you will probably be unable to use some packages. You can try going [back](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/) to 4.1.0 and see if that will install for you.